# Any tool or tricks to convert the image colors into the colors of another image?

Tags: color, images, software-recommendation, tools, color-conversion

#### For example you have these two images

Your image that you want to change its colors:
[image: image to modify]

And the image where you want to based your image colors:

[image: based image colors]

The output image should be the first but all its pixel colors are all present on the second image.

Any recommended tool or tricks to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: @Scott More preferably, I'm looking for an instant or a tool because I have so many images where I want to based my original image.

Comment: So you haven't tried anything yourself?

Comment: @Scott I can't because I don't know a tool or extension that does that for me. 1) Open original image 2) Upload the image where I want to based my original's colors

Comment: Problem is compurts dont know what to color like what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop has a Match Color adjustment available under *Image > Adjustments > Match Color*, however the results may not be quite what you expect.

I'll let you be the judge.

[image]

You might get better results by sampling colours manually from the source image, and manually applying them to the drawing using the Fill Bucket tool.

For example

[image]

Answer (score -2):

#### There is.. https://youtu.be/0pRemmx-kKQ?t=26

**Photoshop**

1. Open your original image and the image where you want to based your original's pixel colors.
2. Then in your original, go to *"Image > Adjustments > Match Color..."*